# Is it possible to debug a userland application from kernel land?

Tags: debugging, winapi, kernel

I'm debugging some win32 application which has loads of anti-debugging, I've tried different stealth options w/ olly and IDA but none of them seem to work. 
I was wondering if it's possible to debug this userland app from kernelland so the app won't know it's being debugged ? if so - which debugger should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging user mode code from kernel mode is most definitely possible, but is a bit more complicated - for instance to get a break in the process before it starts you need to put a breakpoint on the kernel's process creation code or on a NTDLL's user mode code that first executes.  You can try setting up a kernel debugger, using the kernel debugger included in [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx).

Have you tried debugging the process non-invasively?  WinDbg, also in debugging tools for windows, includes a non-invasive option.  This doesn't formally attach to the process and is not as detectable.

However, most anti-debugging suites should also be able to detect if a kernel debugger has been enabled on the machine or if a non-invasive debugger like windbg is running.  Detecting these things isn't too challenging.

Comment: What should I use then ? Will Bochs be an option ?

Comment: Non-invasive windbg would be easier.  I've not used Bochs.

Comment: Bochs is an option, but I imagine it would be a pain (even with a GUI) if there's more than one thread in the entire system, ie, anything more than a bootloader. You'd have to set a manual breakpoint every context switch.